# T-SQL - Return the most recent hire date for each record

Tags: sql, t-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Using T-SQL, I have a table [EMP]:

| Id | SD | ED | Status | Assignment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2020 | 1/15/2020 | A | A1 |
| 1 | 1/16/2020 | 2/1/2020 | T | null |
| 1 | 2/2/2020 | 3/20/2021 | A | null |
| 1 | 3/21/2021 | 10/1/2022 | A | B6 |
| 3 | 10/15/2022 | 5/12/2023 | A | A1 |
| 2 | 1/3/2022 | 2/1/2022 | A | B2 |
| 2 | 2/2/2022 | 11/1/2023 | T | null |
| 1 | 10/2/2022 | 1/1/2023 | T | null |
| 1 | 1/2/2023 | 5/12/2023 | A | A1 |
| 2 | 11/2/2023 | 5/12/2023 | A | A8 |

Id is the Employee Id, SD is the Record Effective Start Date, ED is the Record Effective End Date, and Status is the Employment Status (A = Active, T = Terminated)

I am attempting to add two additional columns, one for the employee's original hire date (the earliest SD for each Id with a Status = 'A'), and another for the most recent hire date for that record (the earliest SD after a record where Status = 'T', or the original hire date).

I can gather the original hire date:

```
    SELECT Id, SD, ED, Status, Assignment, OriginalHireDate
    FROM EMP t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Id, MIN(SD) AS OriginalHireDate
        FROM EMP
        WHERE Status = 'A'
        GROUP BY Id
    ) t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

But I may be overthinking how to grab each record's most recent hire date. The desired output is:

| Id | SD | ED | Status | Assignment | OriginalHireDate | RecentHireDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2020 | 1/15/2020 | A | A1 | 1/1/2020 | 1/1/2020 |
| 1 | 1/16/2020 | 2/1/2020 | T | null | 1/1/2020 | 1/1/2020 |
| 1 | 2/2/2020 | 3/20/2021 | A | null | 1/1/2020 | 2/2/2020 |
| 1 | 3/21/2021 | 10/1/2022 | A | B6 | 1/1/2020 | 2/2/2020 |
| 3 | 10/15/2022 | 5/12/2023 | A | A1 | 10/15/2022 | 10/15/2022 |
| 2 | 1/3/2022 | 2/1/2022 | A | B2 | 1/3/2022 | 1/3/2022 |
| 2 | 2/2/2022 | 11/1/2023 | T | null | 1/3/2022 | 1/3/2022 |
| 1 | 10/2/2022 | 1/1/2023 | T | null | 1/1/2020 | 2/2/2020 |
| 1 | 1/2/2023 | 5/12/2023 | A | A1 | 1/1/2020 | 1/2/2023 |
| 2 | 11/2/2023 | 5/12/2023 | A | A8 | 1/3/2022 | 11/2/2023 |

Comment: The dates in your desired results are different to the dates in your sample data eg Id2 with assignment B2 has SD values that are different. It would make it much easier for your audience if you a) used ISO dates not American dates and b) ordered the data by Id and date.

Comment: I'd add some explanation on why those original/recent hire dates are exactly those. Some extra details on how to reach the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that your rows represent employment starts and end, as indicatd by the `status` column: an employment starts with a "A" status, optionnaly continues with more "A" rows, and then ends with a "T" row.

We can identify employment streaks by comparing the "last" status with the current one; when it transitions from "T" to "A", a new streak starts. Once the islands are defined, we can compute the beginning with just a window min.

```
select e.*,
   min(case when status = 'A' then sd end) over(partition by emp) original_hire_date,
   min(case when status = 'A' then sd end) over(partition by emp, grp) recent_hire_date
from (
    select e.*, 
        sum(case when status = 'A' and lag_status = 'T' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by emp order by sd) grp
    from (
        select e.*, lag(status) over(partition by emp order by sd) lag_status
        from emp e
    ) e
) e
order by id, sd
```

Note that this happily handles series of "A" (as shown in your data) and series of "T", as it only increments on "A"/"T" *transitions*.

| Id | SD | ED | Status | Assignment | lag_status | grp | original_hire_date | recent_hire_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-15 | A | A1 | *null* | 0 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 2020-01-16 | 2020-02-01 | T | *null* | A | 0 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 2020-02-02 | 2021-03-20 | A | *null* | T | 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-02 |
| 1 | 2021-03-21 | 2022-10-01 | A | B6 | A | 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-02 |
| 1 | 2022-10-02 | 2023-01-01 | T | *null* | A | 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-02 |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 | 2023-05-12 | A | A1 | T | 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2023-01-02 |
| 2 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-02-01 | A | B2 | *null* | 0 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2 | 2022-02-02 | 2023-11-01 | T | *null* | A | 0 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2 | 2023-11-02 | 2023-05-12 | A | A8 | T | 1 | 2022-01-03 | 2023-11-02 |
| 3 | 2022-10-15 | 2023-05-12 | A | A1 | *null* | 0 | 2022-10-15 | 2022-10-15 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hzSSdC5b)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I am clear on what your Status values are, as you have multiple A records.  However, it should be as easy as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #t
( Id INT,
  SD DATETIME,
  ED DATETIME,
  Status CHAR(1),
  Assignment VARCHAR(8)
)

INSERT INTO #t VALUES
(1 , '1/1/2020', '1/15/2020', 'A', 'A1'),
(1 , '1/16/2020', '2/1/2020', 'T',null),
(1 , '2/2/2020', '3/20/2021', 'A',null),
(1 , '3/21/2021', '10/1/2022', 'A', 'B6'),
(3 , '10/15/2022', '5/12/2023', 'A', 'A1'),
(2 , '1/3/2022', '2/1/2022', 'A', 'B2'),
(2 , '2/2/2022', '11/1/2023', 'T',null),
(1 , '10/2/2022', '1/1/2023', 'T',  null),
(1 , '1/2/2023', '5/12/2023', 'A', 'A1'),
(2 , '11/2/2023', '5/12/2023', 'A', 'A8')

SELECT  ID, SD, ED, Status, Assignment, 
        (SELECT MIN(SD) FROM #t t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID) AS OriginalHireDate,
        (SELECT MAX(SD) FROM #t t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID) AS RecentHireDate
FROM   #t t1
ORDER BY ID, SD, ED
```

Add additional restrictions in the WHERE clauses of the correlated sub queries